# Apache Camel Default Transaction Manager Data Not Seen in Route

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, apache-camel

I have two routes in Apache Camel. I am using Spring 3 and JPA annotations through Hibernate.

I have multiple data sources and have configured Apache Camel to use one default TransactionManager through SpringTransactionPolicy.

I save the data using DAO and can see the data within the test class by actually finding data. I then use the same DAO within Apache Camel Processor to find the same data, but the data is not found. I don't see why within the test class the data can be found and as soon as I try to look in the Apache Camel custom processor the data cannot be found.

Below is the sample code:

```
    public class Config {
      @Autowired
private TransactionManagerConfig transactionManagerConfig;


      @Bean
public SpringTransactionPolicy defaultTransactionPolicy() throws Exception {
    SpringTransactionPolicy transactionPolicy = new SpringTransactionPolicy();
    transactionPolicy.setTransactionManager((PlatformTransactionManager) transactionManagerConfig.transactionManager());
    return transactionPolicy;
}
  }

public class CustomRouter extends SpringRouteBuilder {

public void configure() throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = getApplicationContext();
    from("someSource")).transacted().unmarshal().jaxb("com.sample.processor.entities").convertBodyTo(Entity.class).to("direct:x")
        .end();
    from("direct:x").transacted().process((CustomProcessor) applicationContext.getBean("customProcessor")).to(someSource);
   }
}


public class CustomProcessor implements org.apache.camel.Processor {

    @Resource
    private StatusDAO statusDAO;

    public CustomProcessor(StatusDAO statusDAO) {
        this.statusDAO = statusDAO;
    }

    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    Status status = null;
    Message message = exchange.getIn();
    Entity entity = (Entity) message.getBody();
    if(entity.getId() != null) {
        // find by id
        status = statusDAO.findById(id);
    }
                status.setName("someName");
    messageStatusDAO.update(status);
    message.setBody(messageStatus);
    exchange.setOut(message);
   }
  }
```

Data is received within the system as XML and changed to a Entity class. I find data using the statusDAO.findById() at this point the DAO returns no data even though the Entity exists.

I setup the test as below:

```
@Transactional
@TransactionalConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
public class CustomTest {

     @Transactional
     @Before
     public void setup throws Exception {
          // setup the Status entity and save it using the DAO
     }

     @Test
     public void testSomething() {
           Status status = statusDAO.findById("id"); // returns the Status that was saved
           MockEndpoint mockEndpoint = (MockEndpoint) this.context.getEndpoint(someDestination);
    mockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
    Status status = producerTemplate.requestBody(source, someXML, Status.class);
    assertNotNull(status);
    mockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
     }
}
```

Using the same transaction manager and the same statusDAO within the Custom Processor does not return the status.

I don't understand why.

Comment: In your config, is "someSource" a file location? Also, where are so setting "source" in your test class (and what to)?

Comment: The someSource in this case is active mq queue and the source in the test class is activemq and the destination being another queue.

Comment: Then assuming there are messages in the queue to consume, I can only suggest looking at how the broker is configured in Camel?

Comment: Not sure whether it is clear. Data is already saved in the database, and the idea to get that same data in the CustomProcessor. What does this have to do with the broker?

Comment: From my understanding, you're using ActiveMQ (a JMS broker) in between the DB and Camel - if ActiveMQ has processed your messages, then Camel isn't receiving its output.